# What is $\frac{p\mathbb Z}{p^\alpha\mathbb Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

May I ask someone elaborate how to treat the quotient group $\frac{p\mathbb Z}{p^\alpha\mathbb Z}$ when $p$ is prime? Any answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the composition of homomorphisms of additive groups
$$
\Bbb Z\longrightarrow p\Bbb Z\longrightarrow p\Bbb Z/p^a\Bbb Z
$$
where the first one is defined by declaring that the image of $1$ is $p$ and the second is the quotient map.

The composite homomorphism is clearly surjective and its kernel is $p^{a-1}\Bbb Z$ (why?). Thus we get an isomorphism
$$
\frac{\Bbb Z}{p^{a-1}\Bbb Z}\simeq\frac{p\Bbb Z}{p^a\Bbb Z}
$$
by the first isomorphism theorem.

Mind that the fact that $p$ is prime has no role in the above.